# Sql for Top 2 repeatable values

Tags: mysql

This is my table x

```
user | action

 1   |  A
 1   |  A
 1   |  B
 1   |  C
 1   |  c
 2   |  A
 2   |  B
 2   |  B
```

I want to know top 2 actions of users. Meaning I want the result as

```
1 | A, C
2 | A, B ( or B, A )
```

I tried a number of ways, such as

```
 select user , action, COUNT(*) from table where user is NOT NULL group by user, action  order by user, COUNT(*);
```

but I cant get the desired result.

Comment: What is *top 2 actions*? Why not A and B for user 1?

Comment: user 1 did action A and C twice and action B once, hence A and C are top 2 actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT user, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(action ORDER BY rank DESC, action), ',', 2) action
  FROM
(
  SELECT user, action, COUNT(*) rank
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY user, action
) q
 GROUP BY user
```

or

```
SELECT user, GROUP_CONCAT(action) action
  FROM
(  
  SELECT user, action, rank, @n := IF(@g = user, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := user
    FROM
  (
    SELECT user, action, COUNT(*) rank
      FROM table1
     GROUP BY user, action
  ) q CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL) i
   ORDER BY user, rank DESC, action
) q2
 WHERE rnum IN(1, 2)
 GROUP BY user
```

Output:

```
| USER | ACTION |
|------|--------|
|    1 |    A,C |
|    2 |    B,A |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49561/7)** demo